# Consistent behavior of a div irrespective of device resolutions

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table inside div with height=500px and its shows 20 rows after there will be vertical scroll bar.

But this behavior is inconsistent on high resolution screen its shows more than 20 rows. How to keep this behavior consistent irrespective of device resolution.

Is there any jQuery method that i can use to fix it.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; height:500px;overflow-y:scroll;width:50%;">
    <table id="physician-table-body" class="table table-bordered table-icon" style="width:100%">
        <tbody id="physicianTableData"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: datatables.js you can use for formatting table, pagination and much more.

Comment: Yes datatable can solve this, but do not wants to use the datatable plugin.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj As per my understanding, you want to display same number of rows in any resolution and after those number of rows you want to display scrollbar for further records. It will affect the row height in different resolutions and may not look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its working without any plugin.

```
var sum=0;
    $('#' + tabName + '-table-body tbody>tr').each(function(index, value) {
        if(index===27)
        {
            var div = $('#' + tabName + '-table-body').parent('div');
            div.css("height", sum);
            return false; 
        }
        sum += $(value).height();
    });
```